# Почему не сохраняется форма?

Tags: python, django

Имеются 2 модели объединенные ключом. При отправке формы в представлении обе формы проходят валидацию и должны сохраниться. Но одна форма сохраняется, а зависимая нет. В чем может быть причина?

```
models.py:
class Industry(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('Название'),max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Отрасль')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Отрасли')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    
class Entity(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Заголовок'), max_length=255, db_index=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(_('Короткое описание'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(_('Контент'), blank=True)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(_('Порядок'), default=0, db_index=True)
    test_field = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Тестовое поле'), max_length=4096)
    test_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,null=True, verbose_name=_('Тестовое поле 2'))
    industry = models.ForeignKey(
        Industry, verbose_name=_('Отрасль'), related_name='industries', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Форма')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Формы')


class PhysicalAddress(BaseModel):
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Адрес'), blank=True, null=True)
    oktmo = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('ОКТМО'),max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Почтовый индекс'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        Entity, verbose_name=_('Организация'), related_name='addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
        verbose_name = _('Физический адрес')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Физические адреса')

forms.py:
class EntityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('ordering', 'status')
        model = models.Entity


class PhysAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('ordering', 'status')
        model = models.PhysicalAddress

views.py:
class EntityPageView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/articles_list.html'
    model = accounts_models.Entity
    form_class = forms.EntityForm
    second_form_class = forms.PhysAddressForm
    success_message = _('Запись успешно добавлена')
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntityPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        items = accounts_models.Entity.objects.published()
        form = self.form_class()
        phys_form = self.second_form_class()

        context.update(
            items=items,
            form=form,
            phys_form=phys_form
        )

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        phys_form = forms.PhysAddressForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and phys_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, phys_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, phys_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, phys_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        phys_form.instance = self.object
        phys_form.save()
        return success_response(self.success_message)

    def form_invalid(self, form, phys_form):
        return form_validation_error_response(form.errors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в методе     `form_valid` у тебя стоит `phys_form.instance = self.object`.
ты таким образом в phys_form подменяешь instance и по сути второй раз сохраняешь первую форму, я думаю ты хотел написать
`phys_form.instance.entity = self.object`